# HTMLDocument.getElementsByTagName() not working with non-html tag names

Tags: vba, dom, ihtmldocument

The following code works well with standard html tags such as *div* or *p*. This deletes the first accruing tag:

```
Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim Node As IHTMLDOMNode

Set htmlDoc = New HTMLDocument
htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = strSomeData

Set Node = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(strSomeTagName).item(0)
Node.parentNode.removeChild Node
```

But when you read a HTMLDocument with Angular tag names such as *article* or *main* or any other non-standard html tag names, getElementsByTagName() fails to read the DOM correctly. The extracted .outerHTML of the extracted node only containes the opening tag and the .innerHTML is left empty. When you than delete such a node, only the opening tag is deleted from the HTMLDocument, therefore destroying the entire logic of the DOM structure.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you got any html snippet as an example? If so then update your post with that otherwise what you have asked is damn broad.

Comment: Are you missing something? No not really. You're just using ancient technology that's not up to dealing with modern HTML.